# How to determine dominance in multi objective optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have very basic question. I'm an engineer by training and have taken undergraduate courses on applied optimization. one of the last chapters in the course was on multi objective optimization (MOO) which the instructor quickly reviewed and did not provide any example context or explanation, so I'm trying to teach MOO myself.

I'm trying to understand the concept of dominance and how to compute `dominance` in the context of multi objective optimization aka Pareto optimality.

Lets suppose I have a vector of functions `f(1)`, `f(2)` and `f(3)`. `f(1)` needs to be minimized. `f(2)` and `f(3)` also need to be minimized. The lowest value `f(2)` and `f(3)`can take is `0`. As an example see below, I have 5 candidates, I would like to assess `dominance` of candidate_1 vs all other candidate. How would can I do that?

Any pseudo code or definition would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: What was the definition of dominance that was taught in your course? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Modified the question, the instructor did not teach MOO very well. So I'm trying to learn myself.

Comment: Can you use [this link](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3116/converting-word-definitions-of-pareto-optimal-into-math-symbols) to propose a definition and solution?